# Text View is altering input characters

Tags: xcode, macos, storyboard

I have a text view that replaces "--" with "-" automatically. I have everything disabled on the text view except for "editable" and "selectable". I'm using the storyboard interface builder. Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: Reading the docs could be useful. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/2866013-smartdashestype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTextView` overrides the settings in the storyboard with the user preferences. If you want to override the user preferences then change the settings in code in `viewDidLoad`.

```
textView.isAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled = false
```